# How to find out what is blocking web page rendering?

Tags: javascript, html

There is website where the server rendering finishes very fast but there is something on the client side which is blocking the rendering for few seconds and then rendering the HTML.

I am guessing it might be some setTimeout or similar; is there any tool or developer tool bars to verify this?

Comment: Have you tried reviewing the source of the `document` and `Resources` tab?

Comment: If you are comfortable using chrome dev tools I would take a heap snapshot only of the blocking render duration so you can see exactly which js functions were running

Comment: what will we know in resources tab?

Comment: Thanks @drewT, let me check how to do that.

Comment: ya ya https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/heap-snapshots?hl=en

Comment: `Resources` should contain `Frames`, see also `Sources`

Comment: can you tell me what to check there, i am seeing that option first time and it shows lot of things in %..

Comment: You can review `localStorage`, `ServiceWorkers`,  the `.html`, `.js` source files

Comment: well since you suspect that javascript is the problem just look under `window` or `document` it's probably there in the heap snapshot

Answer (score 1):

Just capture the network traffic when the page is loading, and see what resource / file is (pending) while the page is loading.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser's developer tools will tell you exactly what is going on.  It could be network, parsing, rendering, anything.

Comment: basically page loads and waits few seconds to show the html, its like a blank screen, how will we know which is doing that?

Comment: @kobe What do your browser's developer tools say is happening?  Either the network area or profiling area will indicate this.

Comment: network panel is not showing anything which is longer, how and where will i know in profiling?

Comment: i am running and its taking for ever, i will wait till it finishes.